# Searching for items in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to say that if it is not one of those operators then it should operate the `if` statement.

```
if item is ("(" , "+" , "*" , "/" , ")" , "–") == False:
```

is what I currently have, and it is not working. How should I write it to make it work?

Comment: Never use the `is` operator to compare for a tuple or a string.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [`not in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) operator here:

```
if item not in ("(", "+", "*", "/", ")", "–"):
```

The `is` operator is used to test an object's identity.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> f1 = Foo()  # An instance of class Foo
>>> f2 = Foo()  # A different instance of class Foo
>>> f3 = f1     # f3 refers to the same instance of class Foo as f1
>>> f1 is f3
True
>>> f1 is f2
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
if item not in ("(" , "+" , "*" , "/" , ")" , "–"):
```

Also:

- You are using the `is` operator in a completely wrong way. NEVER EVER use it if you want to check if two things are "equal" as in "the same string/value/...". ONLY use it to test if two things are actually *the same*. The only case where you really need this as a beginner is to test if something is `None` (e.g. `foo is None`, `foo is not None`)
- `foo == True` and `foo == False` are something you really don't want to use in Python. Simply use `foo` and `not foo` instead.
- Please read (**and follow!**) the [Python style guide (PEP8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!

Answer (score 3):

While the answers posted so far are correct, they can be simpler.

```
if item not in "(+*/.)-": ...
```

Works just as well as the list versions.  This works on the same principle as:

```
>>> x = "Hello, world"
>>> "Hello" in x
True
>>> "H" in x
True
>>> y = "+"
>>> y in "(+*/.)-"
True
```

The reason that this works is that strings are iterable, just like lists, so the `in` operator works as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if item not in ["(" , "+" , "*" , "/" , ")" , "–"]:`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if item not in ["(" , "+" , "*" , "/" , ")" , "–"]:
    ...
    ...
    ...
else:
    ...
```

You can also make it shorter using a string:

```
if item not in "(+*/)–":
    ...
    ...
    ...
else:
    ...
```

But only if your item is a single character.